# Why the ANSI characters don't work after 127 in C even when using an "unsigned char"?

Tags: c

i'm trying to printf an ANSI character bigger than 127 using an unsigned char. The problem is that the character that i get is wrong. For example, if i try to print the character number 161 (¡) i get the number 237 (í). Why?

Yeah, sorry. So, i am using CodeBlocks on Windows 8.1 64 bit. This is the code:

```
unsigned char uc = 160; 
...
printf("unsigned char considered': %c\n",uc);
...
```

Comment: What character-set? And how do you print it? Also, on what system?

Comment: Do you mean that you put something like `printf("%d", '¡')` in your code?  That will – at best – yield some non-portable implementation-defined result.  You cannot have non-ASCII characters in C code.

Comment: Post the code. Your description is too ambiguous to explain what you are really doing.

Comment: The Windows console defaults to the OEM codepage (e.g. 437 or 850), not the ANSI codepage (e.g. 1252). Call [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set a different codepage. Or instead switch `stdout` to wide-character mode (`_O_U16TEXT`) and use `wprintf` with `wchar_t` Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you are doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    unsigned char c = 160;
    printf ("The character is %c\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

How top bit set characters work depends on your terminal emulation. If you have a UTF-8 terminal, for instance, it will be expecting unicode sequences.